# How to convert serialized JSON string back to JSON object?

Tags: arduino-uno, json, convert

How to convert JSON String for example

```
{"f0":100,"f1":100,"f2":100}
```

It is what I get from my esp01 side from I2C communication

Now I want it to get it back to my Arduino side variables `int f0 ,int f1 ,int f2`

But example shown in [web site](https://arduinojson.org) uses kind of different serialized JSON

Example shown,

`char json[] = "{\"sensor\":\"gps\",\"time\":1351824120,\"data\":[48.756080,2.302038]}";`

Can I convert the data I got from I2C communication for using in the method for `deserializeJson(jsonobj, stringofdata)`

I2C communication side of arduino looks like,

```
void receiveEvent(size_t howMany) {
  String datain = "";
  while (0 < Wire.available()) {
    char c = Wire.read();
    datain += c;
  }
  Serial.println(datain);
//be careful can't send too much json data I2C crash!
  Serial.println(datain.length());
  DynamicJsonDocument datajson(100);
  if (deserializeJson(datajson, datain)) {
    Serial.print("deserialization ok ");
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    f0 = datajson["f0"];
    f1 = datajson["f1"];
    f2 = datajson["f2"];

    Serial.println(String(f0) + " " + String(f1) + " " + String(f2));
  }


}
```

In serial monitor I only see this no deserialization worked

```
{"f0":0,"f1":0,"f2":0}
22
```

Comment: the return value of deserializeJson is not boolean.

Comment: You cannot concatenate string literals (`" "`) with +. That just adds the pointer addresses together.

Comment: I tried with ```DeserializationError error```  ```error``` inside if condition still no luck

Comment: Debug errors like that:
```arduino
if (err) { Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: ")) Serial.println(err.c_str())
} else { //your code
}
```

Comment: @Juraj I believe you almost answered my question it is not a Boolean  but however it works as Boolean however for a correct deserialization I need to take the inverse of it that, It was my mistake I first thought that gives a Boolean  as correct deserialization as true its not;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake I did was thinking `deserializeJson(datajson, datain)` gives a Boolean as `true` for correct deserialization but accually it gives an object of `DeserializationError err` so need to check if there is no error thus

The new code

```
// need ! here
  if (!deserializeJson(datajson, datain)) {
    Serial.println("yay it worked");
    Serial.print("deserialization ok ");
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    f0 = datajson["f0"];
    f1 = datajson["f1"];
    f2 = datajson["f2"];

    Serial.print(f0);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(f1);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(f2);

//also tested this way and it works too
    Serial.println(String(f0) + " " + String(f1) + " " + String(f2));
  } else {
    // I was coding here thinking its Boolean before
    //error
  }
```

Comment: For reference, [here is the documentation of `deserializeJson()`](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/json/deserializejson/).